# Why didn't God take or afflict Job's wife?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, family-members, job-iyov-book-of

When testing Job, Satan takes his possessions, flocks, slaves, and sons, but not his wife. She's not even afflicted with any illnesses.

Why is that? Is there a hidden message about her cooperation with Satan?

Answer (score 1):

Job's wife wasn't part of the wager between God and *ha-satan*.

> The Lord said to the accuser,[*ha-satan*] “Have you considered my
> servant Job? There is no one like him on the earth, a blameless and
> upright man who fears God and turns away from evil.” Then the accuser
> answered the Lord, “Does Job fear God for nothing? Have you not put a
> fence around him and his house and all that he has, on every side? You
> have blessed the work of his hands, and his possessions have increased
> in the land. But stretch out your hand now, and touch all that he has,
> and he will curse you to your face.” The Lord said to the accuser,
> “Very well, all that he has is in your power; only do not stretch out
> your hand against him!” So the accuser went out from the presence of
> the Lord.

*Is there a hidden message about her cooperation with Satan?* No. God did not boast of Mrs. Job's righteousness. She isn't part of the bargain. She's just a normal human being. In fact, she isn't even mentioned in the prologue, which many scholars believe is from a different author than the main body of the text. But later in the narrative, she does urge Job to stop standing in his integrity, even to curse God and die.

However, we should not judge her as colluding with the Satan here. Rather, she is in the depths of despair and she gives in to it. Like any human being she is subject to the temptations of the *yetzer harah*. God's wager has resulted in the death of every one of her children, the complete loss of the family's once great wealth, and now the terrible disease that afflicts her husband. The longer Job persists in his righteous course - both insisting that he has not sinned and refusing to curse God - the more Job's suffering *and that of his wife* will only intensify. His wife's despair may be a part of Job's test, but she is not the instigator of the test, nor is there any hint of her willful cooperation with the personalized force of evil.

We should also consider, that when Job's wife advised him to blaspheme and put an end to his suffering, his answer is a gentle rebuke, not a condemnation. “You speak as any foolish woman would speak. Shall we receive good from God and not receive evil?” He does not treat her as being in league with the devil, but as his loving wife for whom he has great compassion. Moreover, in the book's epilogue there is no mention of a new wife, and it seems God greatly rewarded both Job and his wife. This would make no sense if she had been a traitor in league with the enemy.

**Job's wife wasn't part of the wager between Satan and God, but she lost virtually everything that made her life worth living. In that sense, the OP is mistaken to suggest that she wasn't tested. It's true that she momentarily gave in to despair. Who among us would not?**

---

*See a discussion midrashic references to Job's wife [here](https://jwa.org/encyclopedia/article/wife-of-job-midrash-and-aggadah)*

Comment: Thank you, 1. please explain how his wife is not "everything he has". 2. She does not sound as if she lost everything.

Comment: Not sure what you mean in point 1. For point 2, I try to put myself in her place. Has she overheard the conversation between God and Satan? Probably not. Does she know this is all a test to see if Job is really all that God said of him? We don't know.  I think what she does know is that her whole world has been destroyed: 10 children dead, her family's wealth destroyed, her husband leprous and reduced to bemoaning his fate on an ash heap. I don't see her has hoping to live on if her husband curses God and dies. I doubt I would have done any better than she.

Answer (score -1):

The Torah says (Job 2:9):

> Then his wife said to him, Dost thou still retain thy integrity? curse G-d, and die.

The [Malbim](https://www.sefaria.org/Job.2.9?lang=bi&with=Malbim&lang2=en), in his commentary to this posuk explains this to mean:

> After losing all his possessions and children, Job had still blessed G-d. But he now just remains silent. This time, he could not bring himself to do so. His wife taunts him: Are you still resolved to be perfect? Bless G-d once more again and you'll be dead!

So, yes, according to the Malbim, Job's wife was taunting him to blaspheme G-d. However, as I will demonstrate below, there are many mefarshim that discusses the idea that although the wife seems to encourage her husband to sin against G-d, it was an act of protection.

Although, this book is not written by a Jewish author (I apologize if it includes content not appropiate for this site), but the author of ["The Book of Job: A History of Interpretation and a Commentary"](https://books.google.nl/books?id=vCj4DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA59&lpg=PA59&dq=why%20was%20job%27s%20wife%20spared%20judaism&source=bl&ots=YvX24IdRlT&sig=ACfU3U1yqEIDPlIN8faTSHgNS781fcojPA&hl=nl&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj9lLmwqeT6AhVI2aQKHRSLDvEQ6AF6BAgzEAM#v=onepage&q=why%20was%20job%27s%20wife%20spared%20judaism&f=false) cites the grandson of Rashi, Rabbi Yaakov ben Meir Tam, also known as the Rabbeinu Tam. The Rabbeinu Tam explains that the reason why Job's wife said (v.9) "curse G-d and die", means that his wife wanted Job to die, by cursing G-d, by seeing her husband suffer so deeply *(original source needed)*.
The author also cites the Ramban, Nachmanides in connection to Job 3:1.

In the same book, the author mentions a Midrash Rabbah (will add it in later...) that connects Job's wife to Chava. Just like Satan tempted Adam through his wife Chava, soo to Satan tempted Job with his wife.

Bottom line: there is a Midrashic approach that explain that although it might seem that Job's wife was "influenced by evil", the deeper reason was that Job's wife wanted to end the suffering of her husband. Job lost everything that he had. Why suffer longer? Rather, "curse G-d and die" said his wife.

Comment: A fine attempt, thank you, but I don't see why didn't Satan take her (basically my question). Unless she was his accomplice.

Comment: Did not see your comment :) added the last line, maybe that helps.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. The last line directs to a sefer that just makes a joke.